# json data object won't append

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm a newb so go easy:

I can't figure out why this $.ajax function won't append my xhr data to the correct place.

```
    // gets the cache data from our php file
function getcaches() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: "php/findcache.php",
        dataType: "json", // return type data is json
        success: function(data){ // <-- data is in json format
            //parse the json data
            $('#caches').append($('<p>' + data[0].name + '</p>'));
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
    return false;   
}
```

That's the relevant javascript. I know the data is being stored properly in the object because i can see it in firebug...

```
[OU0397] => stdClass Object
    (
        [code] => OU0397
        [name] => A Mighty Oak in the Open
        [location] => 28.527633|-81.125167
        [type] => Virtual
        [status] => Available
    )
```

I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any pointers?

Comment: Why do you think you have a `[0]`?

Comment: Is it data[0].name or data.name?

Comment: I've tried both, neither give me a response

Comment: the data object has three entries though, I only pasted one to save space. How should I address those?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the javascript console? What happens if you try to `alert(data[0])`? `alert(data[0].name)`? Are the objects really keyed rather than being in an array?  Can you do a `for (var key in data)` and see the keys?  See http://jsfiddle.net/ZdZjF/ for an example of the difference between an array and a map.

Comment: What you see in firebug is not a JSON

Answer (score 2):

The code sample has XSS vulnerability (what if name has "<" characters in it?).

Do not add text values to HTML without proper HTML encoding. You can use jQuery's text() method to set element text instead of concatenating strings.

```
$('#caches').append($('<p/>').text(data[0].name));
```

It could be one of the reasons why your output is incorrect.

You can debug your jQuery CSS selector from Firebug or with Chrome developer tools by executing $('#caches') and it will return an array of matched elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Firebug, you set a breakpoint here:

```
$('#caches').append($('<p>' + data[0].name + '</p>'));
```

And then you inspect `data`. Your debug data showed `OU0397` as the key; due to PHP's `json_encode`, that means you are likely given a dictionary. Dictionaries are traversed in a different manner (e.g. `for i in data { ... }`).

You could also consider changing your PHP to return only the first result; this simplifies your JavaScript and reduce network overhead (e.g. use `json_encode(current($data))`).